# C++ OpenGL 2D - Sliding the camera when the player moves

Tags: c++, opengl, viewport

I'm trying to achieve this sort of effect: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HuARqqMuHE8

On frame updates I have:

```
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        gluOrtho2D(left, right, bottom, top); //Window dimensions: 800x600
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();
```

What values do I need to put in the left, right, bottom, top to achieve the effect in the video above?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where you want to place the camera in relationship to the ship will determine the top and left positions. I know there are some weird things that happen with coordinate systems in OpenGL, but this should work:

This will place the ship in the center of the screen at all times:

```
left = shipPos.x - (screenWidth/2.0); // in your case this would be x - 400
top = shipPos.y - (screenHeigh/2.0); // and this would be y - 300
right = left + screenWidth;
bottom = top + screenHeight;
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, thanks. But it doesn't quite simulate the sort of camera shown in the video. In the video, it seems to work the same but the camera is not centered on the player. So, if the player moves left, the view shifts left the amount of pixels the player moved, but somehow still allows the player to move around the whole view, despite the camera following the player.

Comment: Find the change in position and add that to the left and top positions.

Comment: Are you talking about the change in player position?

Comment: Yes. That will center the camera to the player and then move it based on the player's movement.